# Make [objective-c-2.0] a synonym of [objective-c]

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

**Recommendation**

Make [objective-c-2.0](/questions/tagged/objective-c-2.0) a synonym for [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c), with [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c) as the master tag.

**Rationale**

- [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c) currently has 162,074 posts, and [objective-c-2.0](/questions/tagged/objective-c-2.0) has 303 posts.
- Of the 303 posts tagged with [objective-c-2.0](/questions/tagged/objective-c-2.0), [151 posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/155377/posts-tagged-with-objective-c-2-0-but-not-objective-c) are not also tagged with [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c). As a result, some of these posts do not have correct syntax highlighting.
- Objective-C 2.0 has been around [since 2006](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Objective-C_2.0), and the features introduced by Objective-C 2.0, including `@property`, `@synthesize`, and dot syntax, are now standard features of iOS development.
- Questions about Objective-C 2.0 features are also appropriate to be tagged with [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreed; it could even be removed outright. There's no useful information imparted by this tag, no particular distinction to be made between "1.x" (which is never what it's been called) and "2.0" (which isn't really an official name anyways). The language just isn't that standardized, and unlike e.g., the Python 2 -> 3 split, there are no forward or backward compatibility problems. Code in "v1.x" is compilable by a "v2.x" compiler.

Any question about a feature introduced by "v2.0"  would be much better tagged with the base [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c) and [feature-i-am-asking-about](/questions/tagged/feature-i-am-asking-about).